# rudin theorem 1.20 (b) proof

Tags: real-analysis

> (a) If x ∈ **R**, y ∈ **R** and $x > 0$, then there is a positive integer n such that $nx > y$.
>
> (b) If x ∈ **R**, y ∈ **R** and $x < y$, then there exists a p ∈ **Q** such that $x<p<y$ $x<p<y$.
>
> Since x < y, we have $y−x > 0$, and (a) furnishes a positive integer $n$ such that $n(y−x) > 1$.

In (b) we have that $x < y$ which can be expressed as $y-x > 0$.

How does (a) provide that $n(y-x) > 1$ ?

Thank you for any help.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

$x$ and $y$ stand for different things in the two statements. Read (a) as saying:

> if $a \in \mathbb R$, $b \in \mathbb R$, and $a > 0$, then there is a positive integer $n$ such that $na > b$.

If $x < y$ then setting $a = y-x > 0$ and $b = 1$ there exists a positive integer $n$ with $na > b$. That is, $n(y-x) > 1$.

Answer (score 1):

Part a) provides the archemedian property, that an integer times any positive real number can be made larger than any real number. As such, the statement $n(x-y) \ge 1$ is valid for positive $x-y$.